How to Find the product of (1-1/p^2)^1/2 for primes congruent to 1 mod4 using PARI/GP
How can I find the product (1-1/p^2)^1/2 for all primes p=1 mod 4 up to 10^4 using PARI/GP.
forprimestep(p = 2, 10^4,Mod(1,4),print(sqrt(1 - 1/p^2)))

I wrote this code but this just prints out the expression for each individual prime.

For products over sequences of primes it is recommended to use built-in prodeuler function. So PARI/GP code for your task will be still neat one-liner.
> sqrt(prodeuler(p=2, 10^4, if(Mod(p, 4) == 1, 1 - p^-2, 1)))

0.97304214526176447982160122995973409970

Please note, congruence class you want is moved under conditional now.

You need to define a variable to hold the developing product during the loop
product=1.0;
forprimestep(p = 2, 10^4,Mod(1,4),product = product * (sqrt(1 - 1/p^2)));
print(product)

output is 0.97304214526176447982160122995973409967.
